# Trouble getting a self-signed cert working in Postman

Tags: apache, ssl, nginx, postman

I'm finally getting into using SSL on my personal sites, so I started by trying to make a multi-domain self signed cert for my local development (to handle api.mydomain.local, www.mydomain.local, and mydomain.local). I don't know if this was my first mistake, but...

As I couldn't find a single encompassing guide, I started by using two tutorials (from [EasyEngine](https://easyengine.io/wordpress-nginx/tutorials/ssl/multidomain-ssl-subject-alternative-names/) and [DeveloperSide](https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/generating-and-installing-wildcard-and-multi-domain-ssl-certificates)) to create my cert and install it on my host (Win10). I then used a [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-16-04) guide to figure out how to setup my Apache on my dev server (a Ubuntu VM); up to there, no big trouble, other than some minor issues caused by working from multiple guides at the same time.

I go ahead and try to hit my api in Chrome, it gives me an untrusted certificate value as expected, I pass and it works. As far as I know, this means the cert worked? However, when I try to hit my api in Postman, I get an error that indicates it can't accept an untrusted cert, which is fine, as it has a tutorial on [how to fix that](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/28/using-self-signed-certificates-with-postman/). However, it still doesn't work. I can't figure out what else to do to fix this, am I on the right track? Is my cert completely borked? Did I make a core mistake in trying to do a multi-domain cert?

One thing I did notice is that in the Dev Tools security tab, it says

```
Subject Alternative Name missing
```

So I'm not sure if that means my alt names aren't working, but if they weren't, it wouldn't try to load the certificate when I hit it in Chrome, right?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue while writing an article for my website on SSL certificates. So i wrote shell script for the same

```
#!/bin/bash

CERT_COMPANY_NAME=${CERT_COMPANY_NAME:=Tarun Lalwani}
CERT_COUNTRY=${CERT_COUNTRY:=IN}
CERT_STATE=${CERT_STATE:=DELHI}
CERT_CITY=${CERT_CITY:=DELHI}

CERT_DIR=${CERT_DIR:=certs}

ROOT_CERT=${ROOT_CERT:=rootCA.pem}
ROOT_CERT_KEY=${ROOT_CERT_KEY:=rootCA.key.pem}


# make directories to work from
mkdir -p $CERT_DIR

create_root_cert(){
  # Create your very own Root Certificate Authority
  openssl genrsa \
    -out $CERT_DIR/$ROOT_CERT_KEY \
    2048

  # Self-sign your Root Certificate Authority
  # Since this is private, the details can be as bogus as you like
  openssl req \
    -x509 \
    -new \
    -nodes \
    -key ${CERT_DIR}/$ROOT_CERT_KEY \
    -days 1024 \
    -out ${CERT_DIR}/$ROOT_CERT \
    -subj "/C=$CERT_COUNTRY/ST=$CERT_STATE/L=$CERT_CITY/O=$CERT_COMPANY_NAME Signing Authority/CN=$CERT_COMPANY_NAME Signing Authority"
}


create_domain_cert()
{
  local FQDN=$1
  local FILENAME=${FQDN/\*/wild}

  # Create a Device Certificate for each domain,
  # such as example.com, *.example.com, awesome.example.com
  # NOTE: You MUST match CN to the domain name or ip address you want to use
  openssl genrsa \
    -out $CERT_DIR/${FILENAME}.key \
    2048

  # Create a request from your Device, which your Root CA will sign
  if [[ ! -z "${SAN}" ]]; then
    openssl req -new \
      -key ${CERT_DIR}/${FILENAME}.key \
      -out ${CERT_DIR}/${FILENAME}.csr \
      -subj "/C=${CERT_COUNTRY}/ST=${CERT_STATE}/L=${CERT_CITY}/O=$CERT_COMPANY_NAME/CN=${FQDN}" \
      -reqexts san_env -config <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf <(cat ./openssl-san.cnf))
  else
    openssl req -new \
      -key ${CERT_DIR}/${FILENAME}.key \
      -out ${CERT_DIR}/${FILENAME}.csr \
      -subj "/C=${CERT_COUNTRY}/ST=${CERT_STATE}/L=${CERT_CITY}/O=$CERT_COMPANY_NAME/CN=${FQDN}"
  fi


  # Sign the request from Device with your Root CA
  if [[ ! -z "${SAN}" ]]; then
    openssl x509 \
      -sha256 \
      -req -in $CERT_DIR/${FILENAME}.csr \
      -CA $CERT_DIR/$ROOT_CERT \
      -CAkey $CERT_DIR/$ROOT_CERT_KEY \
      -CAcreateserial \
      -out $CERT_DIR/${FILENAME}.crt \
      -days 500 \
      -extensions san_env \
      -extfile openssl-san.cnf
  else
    openssl x509 \
      -sha256 \
      -req -in $CERT_DIR/${FILENAME}.csr \
      -CA $CERT_DIR/$ROOT_CERT \
      -CAkey $CERT_DIR/$ROOT_CERT_KEY \
      -CAcreateserial \
      -out $CERT_DIR/${FILENAME}.crt \
      -days 500 
  fi
}

 METHOD=$1
 ARGS=${*:2}

echo "Called with $METHOD and $ARGS"
if [ -z "${METHOD}" ]; then
  echo "Usage ./sslcerts.sh [create_root_cert|create_domain_cert] <args>"
  echo "Below are the environment variabls you can use:"
  echo "CERT_COMPANY_NAME=Company Name"
  echo "CERT_COUNTRY=Country"
  echo "CERT_STATE=State"
  echo "CERT_CITY=City"
  echo "CERT_DIR=Directory where certificate needs to be genereated" 
  echo "ROOT_CERT=Name of the root cert"
  echo "ROOT_CERT_KEY=Name of root certificate key"
else
  ${METHOD} ${ARGS}
fi
```

You can change the environment variables on the TOP and generate a self-signed certificate using below

```
$ SAN=DNS.1:*.tarunlalwani.com,DNS.2:tarunlalwani.com ./sslcerts.sh create_domain_cert '*.tarunlalwani.com'
```

**Edit 1**

Earlier browsers use to rely on FQDN, but now some of them have started using SAN which is "Subject Alternative Name". Generally openssl doesn't come up v3 extensions configured. SAN is a part of the v3 extensions. So when you generated a self signed certificated it has the correct FQDN (Full qualified domain name) but not SAN. Chrome will show error for these certificates but you will see firefox working fine.

PS: Taken from article http://tarunlalwani.com/post/self-signed-certificates-trusting-them/

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic script! I'll certainly give it a shot when I can. I hope you don't mind if I don't accept your answer just yet; I'm looking to learn as much about where I went wrong as I am to find a solution to it. Plus, I don't totally understand the script, so I need to learn that too :)

Comment: Sure. Read my edit for an explanation. And read the reference links on my article to get a better understanding. And no worries about accepting the answer, you can wait for others to pitch in if you want and accept the answer which you feel is most appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The two articles I used were actually about setting up with SAN, which I thought I setup properly, but I'm guessing I didn't, since I'm getting the error; but that leads to the question, why would it accept the cert for the domain (I gave it a FQDN of `mydomain.local` with the url being `api.mydomain.local`, which was in the SAN.

Comment: @RhoVisions, No idea :-)